# Why initialize a new Random() with unchecked(Environment.TickCount * 31)?

Tags: c#, random

I found this initialization of a `Random` instance:

```
var random = new Random(unchecked(Environment.TickCount * 31));
```

Why not simply use `new Random()`?

Comment: `Random` has some statistical problems with related tick counts. I think the 31 is supposed to fix that. This code is broken in any case because it relies on ticks. A better way, not the best, is `new Random(NewGuid().GetHashCode())`.

Comment: It's an utterly useless bit of code. `Random()` already initializes itself based on the `Environment.TickCount`, and C# is unchecked by default. I really wonder what adding the `* 31` does though.

Answer (score 7):

The keyword `unchecked` prevents an exception from being thrown when the calculation `Environment.TickCount * 31` integer overflows.

The resulting calculation is essentially a random integer (it throws away a bunch of high-order bits), which is used to seed the random number generator.

Note that the [Reference Source for Random](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs) has this code as its parameterless constructor:

```
public Random() 
    : this(Environment.TickCount) {
  }
```

Comment: Why is 31? Such "magic number"? Because I saw it in a lot of places.
https://github.com/natfoth/LunaSkypeBot/blob/master/LunaSkypeBot/Utillities/Extensions.cs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt
https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/ReactiveTrader/blob/master/src/Adaptive.ReactiveTrader.Shared/Extensions/ArrayExtensions.cs

Comment: I don't know.  It might be an error.  The [Lehmer Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) uses 2³¹ as a large Mersenne Prime; maybe that's where it came from.

Comment: 31 == 2^5 - 1 == 11111 (binary). Multiplying with such a number is meant to spread differences: Even if two numbers differ in only one bit, those two numbers each multiplied with 31 will most likely differ in multiple bits. For a proper seeding implementation of a `random` functionality this shouldn't be necessary, though.